# How to assign a counter to every new file name

Tags: c++, string, file-io

I have a method signature like this:

```
vector<int> findRow(string filename);
```

It inputs different files and returns a particular row. I will be using this method on many different files and need to keep a track of which file returns which row. So I wanted to assign a unique file number to each filename and then use this file number to reference the files and their corresponding return values. How do I do this? I'm completely lost!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static local variable as counter, and one or two [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) to map the id to the vector, and possible the id to the filename:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> id_to_row;
std::unordered_map<int, std::string> id_to_file;

// This will be the next id to assign to a row/file
// I.e. the current row-id is `id_counter - 1` if `id_counter > 0`
// It can also be seen as the number of mappings made (or rows loaded)
int id_counter = 0;

std::vector<int>& findRow(std::string filename)
{
    // Do your stuff
    for (...)
    {
        ...

        id_to_row[id_counter].push_back(row_value);

        ...
    }

    // Map the id to the filename as well
    id_to_file[id] = filename;

    // Return a reference to the actual vector, while incrementing id value
    return id_to_row[id_counter++];
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about the some_number. Should I make it global and keep a counter outside my method?

Comment: @sumrania `some_number` is the number you want in the vector, the numbers you get from "the row".

Comment: Oh I guess my post was confusing. I want to assign a unique ID to each filename regardless of what the return type is. So my number should be the unique ID incrementing with each new file name

Comment: @sumrania Then use a global variable, and change the mapping. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about defining a structure (or even a class) `info` that takes a filename and the row number as attributes? Define a vector of `info`. For every file, store name and row in a new `info`, and append to the vector. The index into this vector is the number you woudl like to have.